# Using natural id of a business entity as primary key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would like to check, whether it is recommended to use a natural id (20 digit varchar) as the primary key of a table. I'm using spring-data-jpa.
Will there be any performance issues or any pros & cons with this approach

Answer (score 0):

The type of the primary key of your tables depend on the usage of them. Mostly long datatype is used. If your use case is to have an natural primary key for your table, which has a special meaning like an social security number then use it. JPA does not care about it if its a natural or primary key. One difference with natural primary keys compared to generated primary keys is, that JPA does not have to execute a query for retrieving the next value of the primary key. But this is hardly considered a performance issue.

JPA just creates the queries (insert/update/delete) for you and maps the results to java objects.

Maybe this doc helps you as well https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing